# How to convert this C++ code into C# code? What syntax am I forgetting?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, syntax

Google is flooded with Unity3D & XNA resources. It is quite difficult to search for anything dealing with C# without the results being overwhelmingly Unity or XNA based. To even find good tutorials, I had to find a book on amazon and then google the author with -XNA -Unity, lol.

My C++ code is organized nicely with each separate major class being its own file, in an organized directory.

```
Game.cpp
Init.cpp
Render.cpp
Update.cpp
```

Game.cpp, being main(), where my game runs and calls Init, Render, and Update.

```
class Game
{
public:
Game();
private:
void Init();
void Update(sf::Time deltaTime);
void Render();
sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
};

int main()
{
Init();

while (mWindow.isOpen())
{
    Update(TimePerFrame);
    Render();
}
}
```

And of course, Init.cpp

```
#include "Game.hpp"

void Game::Init()
{
mWindow.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
}
```

Now, I have the C# bindings for SFML and switched from Code::Blocks to VS2012. I've been working with C++ for so long that I am having some trouble with C#. I went through some tutorials to refresh myself with the syntax, but there is something I'm still not remembering. Obviously, this is a dumb question. However, google is not very much help due to how overwhelmingly swarmed C# is with Unity & XNA results, and I just can't remember how to do this right.

I want to have the same separate files,

```
 Game.cs
 Init.cs
 Update.cs
 Render.cs
```

However, I can't even get it to function in a single class.

Game.cs

```
class Game
{
    public void Main()
    {
        // Create the main window
        RenderWindow mWindow = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(1200, 1200), "SevenBlack");
        mWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClose);
        Color windowColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);

        //Initialize Game
        Init();

        while (mWindow.IsOpen())
        {
                Update(TimePerFrame);
        }
            Render();
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        mWindow.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    }

    private void Update(long dt)
    {
    }

    private void Render()
    {

        mWindow.Clear(windowColor);
        mWindow.Display();
    }

}
```

I get "The name 'mWindow' does not exist in the current context.

```
    private void Game::Init()
    {
        mWindow.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    }
```

Does not work either, since this is C#.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? I got the answer...lol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mWindow is not declared as a class level variable, so its only scope is in main.  Do this to allow the variable to be seen to the entire class.

```
class Game
{
    private RenderWindow mWindow;

    public void Main()
    {
        // Create the main window
        mWindow = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(1200, 1200), "SevenBlack");
...
```

Comment: DUR! Thank you. Idk what I was thinking.